# Working with an Excel file where worksheets are hidden

Tags: c#, excel

Currently I'm pro-grammatically opening an excel file and editing the sheet. I have existing code that works when `Show Sheet tabs` is turned on from Excel Options - Advanced.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileLocation);

//Add the Content sheet
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet1");
```

But the sheet I'm currently working with has `Show Sheets Tabs` turned off and the above code no longer works, crashes each time it tries to grab the sheet.

May I ask how do I work with the excel file if `Show Sheet Tabs` is turned off

Comment: I used to use the MS Interop / COM objects to manipulate Excel workbooks, but I found that it is easier using EPPlus.  You may want to try it.  https://epplus.codeplex.com.

Comment: Hmm your code seems to work fine for me regardless of the tabs display mode. What is the get_Item method? To get a worksheet object you can simply say: `Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets["Sheet1"];`